# node.js sending mails with a delay

Tags: javascript, node.js, email

I am doing a simple thing but that isn't working.

What I want to do is send mails with a delay of 30 seconds.

Here's the code:

```
user.forEach(function(data) {


    var locals = {
        fname: data.Name,
        your_name: data.From,

    }

    template.render(locals, function(err, results) {

        if (err) {
            return console.error(err)
        } else {
            transporter.sendMail({

                to: data.Email,
                subject: "Welcome",
                replyTo: data.ReplyTo,
                html: results.html,
                text: results.text,
            }, function(error, info) {
                console.log("here");
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
                };

            });
        }

    });
});
```

Here user is an array of objects with details like Email,from,Name etc.

Each object in array has details of a particular mail to be sent.

I want to send a mail and wait for 30s and then send the second one..and wait and so on.

I have used setInterval and also npm sleep, but that isn't working. It waits for 30s and then sends all mails at once.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace syncronous forEach with asynchronous implementation.
**Option1.** Use async.js [eachLimit](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.eachLimit) and call callback with delay of 30 seconds
**Option2.** You can write wrapper for your send email function like:

```
var emails = ['email1', 'email2' /*...*/];
function sendEmailAndWait(email, callback){
    // your stuff
    transporter.sendMail(email, function(error, info) {
        // handle results
        if(!emails.length) return callback();
        setTimeout(function () {
            sendEmailAndWait(emails.shift(), callback);
        }, 30*1000)
    })
}
sendEmailAndWait(emails.shift(), function(){  /* allDone */});
```

Comment: Recurrsive functions fails if call stack limit is reached. Imagine 5000 emails in queue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 setTimeout(function() {
  template.render(locals, function(err, results) {

    if (err) {
        return console.error(err)
    } else {
        transporter.sendMail({

            to: data.Email,
            subject: "Welcome",
            replyTo: data.ReplyTo,
            html: results.html,
            text: results.text,
        }, function(error, info) {
            console.log("here");
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
            };
        });
    }
});
 }, 3000);
```